# React native state field is undefined when calling setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

When I try to call setState on my state, part of it stays unchanged since it is undefined in setState call.

My state:

```
state = {
    result: '',
    inputValue: ''
}
```

And part where I call setState:

```
const result = this.state.result;
let inputValue = this.state.inputValue;
inputValue = '';

if (result !== '') {
    debugger
    this.setState({ result: '0', inputValue: inputValue }, () =>
        console.log(this.state.inputValue + ' result: ' + this.state.result)
    )
}
```

And console.log gives me unchanged value. Weird part of this is that, when I call setState in other parts it's working and updating state field. Only in this one call stays unchanged.

Comment: You're not calling it within `constructor` are you?

Comment: Could you include your entire component? It's difficult to see if something is wrong, since `inputValue` is an empty string initially, and you also set it to an empty string in `setState`

Comment: No, I'm calling it in some anonymous function.

Comment: @Tholle I have some kind of calculator and all I do with inputValue is expanding it with setState to be like this: inputValue = '1 + 2 * 3' and when I try to call the above code in setState inputValue stays the same.

Comment: Your code seems correct. I think the problem is you have not assigned any value to `result` so it is not executing if statement
have look at here https://codesandbox.io/s/2wo5j435pr

Comment: @Revansiddh No, result has some value and it enters in this statement and I get this log: 
e.g : '1 +2 + 3' result: 0
Result is changed but inputValue is not.

Comment: You're setting `inputValue` to an empty string right before you call setState, why are you expecting inputValue to change?

Comment: @ajthyng Previously I had some value in inputValue e.g. '1 + 2 * 4 / 1' and when I get result I need to reset input field, and that's why I have empty string there.